# Does NSURLConnection use TLSv1.2 by default?

Tags: ios, ssl, nsurlconnection

According to Apple:

> If your application implements a TLS client using the CFStream APIs or the SecureTransport APIs, it will now default to using a TLS 1.2 handshake when connecting to a TLS server.

Reference:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2287/_index.html

However, in my application, I am not using CFStream API. I am using an NSURLConnection. For NSURLConnection, is the default TLS 1.2 also?